# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (2198,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a text classification model with cnn but I got this error. I have also tried to make input_dim=(2198,) but does not work also.
So, how can I determine input dimension right and is there any processing on text data like this ?Normalization for example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  read dataset

paths = {
    'amazon': 'D:\\NLP\\sentiment labelled sentences\\amazon_cells_labelled.txt',
    'imdb': 'D:\\NLP\\sentiment labelled sentences\\imdb_labelled.txt',
    'yelp': 'D:\\NLP\\sentiment labelled sentences\\yelp_labelled.txt'
}

data_fame = []
for source, path in paths.items():
    df = pd.read_csv(path, names=['sentence', 'label'], sep='\t')
    df['source'] = source  # Add another column filled with the source name amazon,  imdb, yelp
    data_fame.append(df)

df = pd.concat(data_fame)

#  split data frame into features and labels
X, y = [], []
for i in range(len(df)):
    X.append(df.iloc[i][0])
    y.append(df.iloc[i][1])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 2)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 2)

x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=0)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=0)

#  define CNN model

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim=x_train.shape[0]))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=90, batch_size=16, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
model.save('model.h5')
```

Comment: Could you post the shape of `x_train` and `y_train`? And by the way, you are using a Vanilla Neural Network not CNN

Comment: Good note :)
```x_train shape :  (2198,)``` and ```y_train shape :  (2198, 2)```

Comment: In the first `Dense` layer, you need to set the `input_dim = x_train.shape[1]`.

Comment: It gives this error ```IndexError: tuple index out of range```

Comment: How is that so? You have expanded the dimension using `np.expand_dims`. If you don't mind, state the dimension of `x_train` and `y_train` before `to_categorical` and before `np.expand_dims`

Comment: First of all thanks for you help I really appreciate that.
Shape before ```np.expand_dims``` and ```to _categorical``` is that ```x_train shape :  (2198,)``` and ```y_train shape :  (2198,)```.

Comment: And what is the shape after `to_categorical` and `np.expand_dims`?

Comment: i believe you have some miss understanding here @SaharMetwally, `expand_dim` will add a dimention before x_train, which means, you have the shape of (1, 2198) which is wrong !!! this means you have a data with 2198 features!! no Neural net can train this, i recommend using `reshape((n, m))` you can use `n=-1` and `m=1` but since i don't know how many features you have i can't completely suggest anything

Comment: Is my data should look like this: ```[['One thing I hate is the mode set button at the side.']
 ['In the span of an hour, I had two people exclaim "Whoa - is that the new phone on TV?!?']
 ['The food was great as always, compliments to the chef.']]``` 
or it should be like this :
 ```['One thing I hate is the mode set button at the side.'
 'In the span of an hour, I had two people exclaim "Whoa - is that the new phone on TV?!?'
 'The food was great as always, compliments to the chef.']```

Comment: I think I solved the above error now data shape ```x_train shape :  (2198, 1)``` and  ```y_train shape :  (2198, 2)``` but now I got this error ```ValueError: could not convert string to float```. Any help?